# How to insert all dropdown record at a time?

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert, html-select

I have a huge number of records in a drop-down box(approximately 27000 or more).

HTML -

```
<select name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer">
    <option value="">Select a Builder</option>
    <option value="1-hull">#1 Hull</option>
    <option value="49er">49er</option>
    <option value="a-m-f">A M F</option>
    <option value="a-m-manufacturing">A&amp;M Manufacturing</option>
    <option value="a1-custom-trailers">A1 Custom Trailers</option>
     - -    -    -  -      -
     -     -   -    -   -  -
    <option value="zuma">Zuma</option>
</select>
```

Above drop-down I collect this data from different website. I want to put in my own website with dynamic content. I have tried to insert one by one it is not possible to insert all record in single handed. So I want to any shortcut method for insert all these text in my `MySQL` database table. I need option inner HTML text will inserting into my database table.

If I will get all the option text in an `Array` then easily I can manage it. But I am confused how to get all text in `Array` by using `PHP` code.

Comment: you can do a search and replace in notepad++ or s.th. like that. You also can use a simple regex preg_match_all(). I can give you the regex: preg_match_all('/>(.*?)<\//','<select......',$matches);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with preg_match_all

```
<?php

$string = '<option value="">Select a Builder</option>
    <option value="1-hull">#1 Hull</option>
    <option value="49er">49er</option>
    <option value="a-m-f">A M F</option>
    <option value="a-m-manufacturing">A&amp;M Manufacturing</option>
    <option value="a1-custom-trailers">A1 Custom Trailers</option>
    <option value="zuma">Zuma</option>
';

preg_match_all('/>(.*?)<\//',$string,$matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`DOM Document`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is your buddy,

```
$str = '<select name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer">
        <option value="">Select a Builder</option>
        <option value="1-hull">#1 Hull</option>
        <option value="49er">49er</option>
        <option value="a-m-f">A M F</option>
        <option value="a-m-manufacturing">A&amp;M Manufacturing</option>
        <option value="a1-custom-trailers">A1 Custom Trailers</option>
        <option value="zuma">Zuma</option>
        </select>';    

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);

$options = $doc->getElementsByTagName('option');

foreach ($options as $option) {
    $value[] = $option->nodeValue;
}

$value; // will contain array with all option values
```

[Why you should not parse HTML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3113793)